# Azure SQL Managed Instance and Azure Active Directory Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-authentication, azure-sql-managed-instance

**Question**: In `Azure SQL Managed Instance`, what is the procedure for setting `Password Expiration` when using `Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication`? As shown below, in `SSMS`, I see `Password Expiration` option is grayed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set **`Password expiration`** policy for Azure AD user accounts, you need to have **Global Administrator** role on your tenant.

If you don't have that role, contact admin and get yourself assigned with **Global Administrator** role like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Select user -> Assigned roles -> Add assignments***

[image]

Login to **[Microsoft 365 admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/)** with above **Global admin** credentials and follow below steps to set *password expiration policy*:

***Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Settings -> Org settings -> Security & privacy***

[image]

By **default**, this option is set to passwords ***never expire*** for entire organization like below:

[image]

If you want to set **password expiration** for particular number of days, uncheck the box and enter the number like below:

[image]

If you want to set **password expiration** policy for ***specific*** user, you can use below PowerShell commands:

```
Connect-AzureAD

#To check the expiration policy for a password of specific user
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId <userID/UPN> | Select-Object UserprincipalName,@{
    N="PasswordNeverExpires";E={$_.PasswordPolicies -contains "DisablePasswordExpiration"}  
}  

#To set password to expire
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId <userID/UPN> -PasswordPolicies None
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Set an individual user's password to expire - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/set-password-to-never-expire?view=o365-worldwide#set-a-password-to-expire)